# IBM JVM Java Core Dump created on crash

Tags: java, jvm, dump, datastage

I couldn't find a solution on other forums and websites so I thought I'd come here.

When I try to run an Information Server application (i.e. DataStage Infosphere Designer Client), it shows the copyright splash screen but it doesn't show the login screen. If I look at the Process tab in the task manager, I can see that the DataStage Infosphere Designer Client pops up then disappears (looks like something is killing the process). I also notice that 3 files are created in the software directory: Snap*****.trc, javacore*****.txt, and core*****.dmp

In the text file, I have the following:

```
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "gpf" (00002000) received 
1TIDATETIME    Date:                 2014/12/10 at 18:17:57
1TIFILENAME    Javacore filename:    C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic\javacore.20141210.181756.4956.0002.txt
1TIREQFLAGS    Request Flags: 0x81 (exclusive+preempt)
1TIPREPSTATE   Prep State: 0x100 ()
1TIPREPINFO    Exclusive VM access not taken: data may not be consistent across javacore sections
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ================================
2XHOSLEVEL     OS Level         : Windows XP 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 2
2XHCPUS        Processors -
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : x86
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 4
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
NULL           
1XHEXCPCODE    J9Generic_Signal_Number: 00000004
1XHEXCPCODE    ExceptionCode: C0000005
1XHEXCPCODE    ExceptionAddress: 09C40340
1XHEXCPCODE    ContextFlags: 0001007F
1XHEXCPCODE    Handler1: 0846A120
1XHEXCPCODE    Handler2: 084CC0E0
1XHEXCPCODE    InaccessibleAddress: DD55B4BF
NULL           
1XHEXCPMODULE  Module: C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\j9ute24.dll
1XHEXCPMODULE  Module_base_address: 09C30000
1XHEXCPMODULE  Offset_in_DLL: 00010340
NULL           
1XHREGISTERS   Registers:
2XHREGISTER      EDI: DD55B4BF
2XHREGISTER      ESI: 0853F2E0
2XHREGISTER      EAX: DD55B4BF
2XHREGISTER      EBX: 08FD96F0
2XHREGISTER      ECX: 08FDAB28
2XHREGISTER      EDX: DD55B4C0
2XHREGISTER      EIP: 09C40340
2XHREGISTER      ESP: 0028CA9C
2XHREGISTER      EBP: 08EA5D00
2XHREGISTER      EFLAGS: 00010216
2XHREGISTER      GS: 002B
2XHREGISTER      FS: 0053
2XHREGISTER      ES: 002B
2XHREGISTER      DS: 002B
NULL           
1XHFLAGS       VM flags:00000000
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CIJAVAVERSION 1INTERNAL      An exception occurred attempting to access in-flight data. Internal diagnostics:
NULL           
2INTERNAL                J9Generic_Signal_Number: 00000004
2INTERNAL                ExceptionCode: C0000005
2INTERNAL                ExceptionAddress: 093D12A0
2INTERNAL                ContextFlags: 0001007F
2INTERNAL                Handler1: 093DADC0
2INTERNAL                Handler2: 084CC0E0
2INTERNAL                InaccessibleAddress: DD55B4BF
NULL           
2INTERNAL                Module: C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\j9dmp24.dll
2INTERNAL                Module_base_address: 093D0000
2INTERNAL                Offset_in_DLL: 000012A0
NULL
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 2000000 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 2000000 
NULL           
1STSEGTYPE     Internal Memory
NULL           segment  start    alloc    end       type     bytes
NULL           
1STSEGTYPE     Object Memory
NULL           segment  start    alloc    end       type     bytes
1STSEGMENT     08540854 1A030000 1C030000 1C030000  00000009 2000000
NULL           
1STSEGTYPE     Class Memory
NULL           segment  start    alloc    end       type     bytes
NULL           
1STGCHTYPE     GC History  
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       LOCKS subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
NULL           
1LKPOOLINFO    Monitor pool info:
2LKPOOLTOTAL     Current total number of monitors: 0
NULL           
1LKMONPOOLDUMP Monitor Pool Dump (flat & inflated object-monitors):
NULL           
1LKREGMONDUMP  JVM System Monitor Dump (registered monitors):
2LKREGMON          Thread global lock (0x0898CFF0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Windows native console event lock lock (0x0898D044): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          NLS hash table lock (0x0898D098): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          portLibrary_j9sig_async_monitor lock (0x0898D0EC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          getnameinfo monitor lock (0x0898D140): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Hook Interface lock (0x0898D194): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &(vm->bytecodeTableMutex) lock (0x0898D1E8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Hook Interface lock (0x0898D23C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          dump tokens mutex lock (0x0898D290): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_Forge lock (0x0898D2E4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_SublistPool lock (0x0898D338): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_SublistPool lock (0x0898D38C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_SublistPool lock (0x0898D3E0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_SublistPool lock (0x0898D434): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_SublistPool lock (0x0898D488): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Undead Segment List Monitor lock (0x0898D4DC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Hook Interface lock (0x0898D530): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Hook Interface lock (0x0898D584): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_ParallelDispatcher::slaveThread lock (0x0898D5D8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_ParallelDispatcher::shutdownCount lock (0x0898D62C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_ParallelDispatcher::synchronize lock (0x0898D680): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_WorkPackets::inputList lock (0x0898D6D4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_WorkPackets::allocatingPackets lock (0x0898D728): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          MM_GCExtensions::gcStats lock (0x0898D77C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &RAS_GLOBAL_FROM_JAVAVM(triggerOnGroupsWriteMutex,vm) lock (0x0898D7D0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &RAS_GLOBAL_FROM_JAVAVM(triggerOnTpidsWriteMutex,vm) lock (0x0898D824): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &vm->verboseStateMutex lock (0x0898D878): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM thread list lock (0x0898D8CC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM exclusive access lock (0x0898D920): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM Runtime flags Mutex lock (0x0898D974): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM Extended method block flags Mutex lock (0x0898D9C8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Async event mutex lock (0x0898DA1C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          JIT/GC class unload mutex lock (0x0898DA70): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM bind native lock (0x0898DAC4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM Statistics List Mutex lock (0x0898DB18): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Field Index Hashtable Mutex lock (0x0898DB6C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM class loader blocks lock (0x0898DBC0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM class table lock (0x0898DC14): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM string table lock (0x0898DC68): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM segment lock (0x0898DCBC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM JNI frame lock (0x0898DD10): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM GC finalize master lock (0x0898DD64): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM GC finalize run finalization lock (0x0898DDB8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM memory space list lock (0x0898DE0C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM JXE description lock (0x0898DE60): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM AOT runtime init lock (0x0898DEB4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM monitor table lock (0x0898DF08): Flat locked by "(unnamed thread)" (0x0853F000), entry count 1
2LKREGMON          VM volatile long lock (0x0898DF5C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM mem segment list lock (0x0898DFB0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM mem segment list lock (0x0898E004): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          VM mem segment list lock (0x0898E058): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          FinalizeListManager lock (0x0898E0AC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &(jvmtiData->mutex) lock (0x0898E100): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &(jvmtiData->redefineMutex) lock (0x0898E154): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          BCVD verifier lock (0x0898E1A8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          XshareclassesVerifyInternTreeMon lock (0x0898E1FC): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          global mapMemoryBuffer mutex lock (0x0898E250): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          &(classLoader->mutex) lock (0x0898E2A4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          Thread public flags mutex lock (0x0898E2F8): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          jvmriDumpThread lock (0x0898E34C): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          tracemon lock (0x0898E3A0): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          tracemon lock (0x0898E3F4): <unowned>
2LKREGMON          jvmriDumpThread lock (0x0898E448): <unowned>
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       THREADS subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
NULL           
1XMCURTHDINFO  Current thread
NULL           ----------------------
3XMTHREADINFO      "(unnamed thread)" J9VMThread:0x0853F000, j9thread_t:0x0896E124, java/lang/Thread:0x00000000, state:R, prio=0
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x1898, native priority:0x5, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           No Java callstack associated with this thread
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               unsubscribe+0xa210 (0x09C40340 [j9ute24+0x10340])
4XENATIVESTACK               JVM_OnUnload+0xbb0 (0x08A32D60 [j9trc24+0x2d60])
4XENATIVESTACK               J9VMDllMain+0x97c (0x08A3429C [j9trc24+0x429c])
4XENATIVESTACK               LdrUnloadDll+0x99 (0x77311320 [ntdll+0x41320])
4XENATIVESTACK               FreeLibrary+0x15 (0x76012D2C [KERNELBASE+0x12d2c])
4XENATIVESTACK               j9port_init_library+0x573d (0x084CCEFD [J9PRT24+0xcefd])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlFreeHeap+0x7e (0x772FE023 [ntdll+0x2e023])
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x51E84D8D)
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x50FFCE8B)
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x8F8D5030)
NULL
NULL           
1XMTHDINFO     Thread Details
NULL           ------------------
NULL           
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x1C84, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15 (0x772F015D [ntdll+0x2015d])
4XENATIVESTACK               WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x8e (0x758119F8 [kernel32+0x119f8])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetCLRFunction+0xc7af (0x69C40FAE [clr+0xe0fae])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetCLRFunction+0xc705 (0x69C40F04 [clr+0xe0f04])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetCLRFunction+0xc634 (0x69C40E33 [clr+0xe0e33])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x1D48, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15 (0x772EF8D1 [ntdll+0x1f8d1])
4XENATIVESTACK               WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43 (0x75811194 [kernel32+0x11194])
4XENATIVESTACK               DllUnregisterServerInternal+0x5507 (0x69B70BF3 [clr+0x10bf3])
4XENATIVESTACK               DllUnregisterServerInternal+0x554e (0x69B70C3A [clr+0x10c3a])
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x69B6242D [clr+0x242d])
4XENATIVESTACK               LogHelp_TerminateOnAssert+0x2d0b6 (0x69C055BE [clr+0xa55be])
4XENATIVESTACK               LogHelp_TerminateOnAssert+0x2d40c (0x69C05914 [clr+0xa5914])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x17127 (0x69BD82F7 [clr+0x782f7])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x17195 (0x69BD8365 [clr+0x78365])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x17262 (0x69BD8432 [clr+0x78432])
4XENATIVESTACK               SetRuntimeInfo+0xef1 (0x69C4B5A1 [clr+0xeb5a1])
4XENATIVESTACK               GetPrivateContextsPerfCounters+0x5965 (0x69CF36F8 [clr+0x1936f8])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x138C, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15 (0x772F015D [ntdll+0x2015d])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x5B4, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0x12 (0x772F1F46 [ntdll+0x21f46])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0xBB8, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0x12 (0x772F1F46 [ntdll+0x21f46])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
3XMTHREADINFO      Anonymous native thread
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x7CC, native priority: 0x0, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               ZwDelayExecution+0x15 (0x772EFD91 [ntdll+0x1fd91])
4XENATIVESTACK               Sleep+0xf (0x760144A5 [KERNELBASE+0x144a5])
4XENATIVESTACK               CoGetTreatAsClass+0x325e (0x74FFD98D [ole32+0x2d98d])
4XENATIVESTACK               CoGetTreatAsClass+0x314b (0x74FFD87A [ole32+0x2d87a])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7581338A [kernel32+0x1338a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77309F72 [ntdll+0x39f72])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77309F45 [ntdll+0x39f45])
NULL
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       CLASSES subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CLTEXTCLLOS   
1CLTEXTCLLSS   
2CLTEXTCLLOADER
3CLNMBRLOADEDLIB
3CLNMBRLOADEDCL
1CLTEXTCLLIB   
1CLTEXTCLLOD   
2CLTEXTCLLOAD  
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       Javadump End section
NULL           ---------------------- END OF DUMP -------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to read this file or know how to solve this issue?

I have already tried reinstalling the software, restarting my computer, reinstalling JRE and JDK. I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at a tool called IBM Heap Analyzer. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091

Per the site... it does...

```
List of Java heap leak suspects
Recommendation of the size of kCluster
List of gaps among allocated objects/classes/arrays
Java objects/classes/arrays search engine
List of objects/classes/arrays by type name
List of objects/classes/arrays by object name
List of objects/classes/arrays by address
List of objects/classes/arrays by size
List of objects/classes/arrays by size of child
List of objects/classes/arrays by number of child
List of objects/classes/arrays by frequency
List of available heap spaces by size
Tree view of Java heap dump
Loading/saving processed Java heap dumps.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems like using IBM JVM over Windows XP.
The crash seems comes from IBM JVM DLL.

> 1XHEXCPMODULE  Module:
>   C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\j9ute24.dll

It seems JVM itself problem.
I think, it is better to install other JVM (Oracle JVM)

Comment: Yeah I took a look at it and I have attempted to reinstall JDK and JRE. Sometimes it would fix it but after a few days, I get the above error again. There seems to be a memory leak somewhere but I can't quite pin point it nor know how to fix it.